# Electron / jquery Adding a loading animated.gif to a new opening window (Animation stops)

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I have an electron project which opens a new window (an index.html file)

In the opening new window at the body, I have added the animated.gif

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>

    <img id="loading" src="loading.gif" alt="" />


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // code for loading stuff here..
        $('#loading').hide();

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the rest of the body will load and the .gif is replaced.

My problem is that the loading of the data in the body is so busy that the gif animation stops working.

Does anyone know of any way then I can avoid this from happening?

Comment: does an element animated via css continue to animate during load?

Comment: I haven't tried a css animation, only an animated.gif ... I guess its something I could try

Comment: Let me know if you'd like an answer demonstrating that

Comment: Sure, any help would be very helpful

Comment: No worries, does the answer below help?

Comment: Yes, going to see if it has the same issue as the gif or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a CSS animation to achieve a loading sequence [that runs independently of the UI thread](https://www.phpied.com/css-animations-off-the-ui-thread/) (ie where your JS/script code is executed).

A simple CSS-only spinner like this should continue to animate while your app is busy during startup:

```css
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.loading {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  width:1rem;
  height:1rem;
  display:block;
  
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<i class="loading"></i>
```